# Finding all possible combinations of placemenet on grid

Tags: java, combinations

I'm looking for a way to get all possible combinations of placing n objects in a w*h grid.
What I need to answer is a question like: in what ways can one place n pawns on the chessboard. So for example for two pawns and 2x2 grid my expected result would be:

```
((0, 0, "p1"), (0, 1, "p2"))
((0, 0, "p1"), (1, 1, "p2"))
((0, 0, "p1"), (1, 0, "p2"))
((0, 1, "p1"), (1, 1, "p2"))
((0, 1, "p1"), (0, 0, "p2"))
((0, 1, "p1"), (1, 0, "p2"))
((1, 0, "p1"), (0, 1, "p2"))
((1, 0, "p1"), (1, 1, "p2"))
((1, 0, "p1"), (0, 0, "p2"))
((1, 1, "p1"), (0, 0, "p2"))
((1, 1, "p1"), (0, 1, "p2"))
((1, 1, "p1"), (1, 0, "p2"))
```

How can I do it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Put all items in a collection, put all positions in a collection, iterate over both checking for collisions.

```
boolean foundNewSolutionLastIteration = true;
while (foundNewSolutionLastIteration) {
    foundNewSolutionLastIteration = false;
    List<Pawn> pawns = new ArrayList<Pawn>()
    ... Fill the colelction ...
    List<GridSquare> positions = new ArrayList<GridSquare()
    ... Fill the collection ...
    for (Pawn p : pawns) {
        for (GridSquare square : positions) {
             ... Check if gridsquare contains pawn, else put it in there
             ... Check if all pawns have been placed if so it's a valid position
             ... Is this a new solution? if so set foundNewSolutionLastIteration to true
        }
    }
}
```

Each iteration shouild recford the position so it can be excluded in teh next loop

Comment: Hi, your solution would give me one possible solutions of placing pawns, what I want is to find ALL of such solutions. I might not write clearly enough - what I need at the result is a collection of collections and in each of these there should be n triples like (0, 0, "p1"), (0, 1, "p2"), ... (each collection contains one solution).

Comment: You need to put that into a loop and iterate over it until you don't find a new solution... (I've edited the answer to reflect this)